# Prove that if f satisfies $|f(x,y)| \leq x^2 + y^2$ then $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am given that $f$ is a function that satisfies $|f(x,y)| \leq x^2 + y^2$ for all $(x,y) \in \Bbb{R^2}$ and I am trying to show that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ I have some ideas on how to proceed but Im not sure if they are correct

to check for differentiability by definition I need to show that $lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)}\frac{|R_{1,(a,b)}(x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$
well then $lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)}\frac{|R_{1,(a,b)}(x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{|f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)x-f_y(0,0)y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \frac{|f(x,y)|-|f(0,0)|-|f_x(0,0)x|-|f_y(0,0)y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ now my question is can I claim that $|f_x(x,y)| \leq 2x$ and similarly that 
$|f_y(x,y)| \leq 2y$

Comment: What do you think the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ will be?

Comment: $f_x(0,0)=0$ and $f_y(0,0)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You need a linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\lim_{\vert\vert(x,y)\vert\vert\rightarrow0}\frac{\vert f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L(x,y)\vert}{\vert\vert(x,y)\vert\vert}\rightarrow0.$$
In this case your guess is that the $L$ is identically $0$ (because the partial derivatives in $0$ should be both $0$). Moreover the inequality gives also $f(0,0)=0$, thus
$$\lim_{\vert\vert(x,y)\vert\vert\rightarrow0}\frac{\vert f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L(x,y)\vert}{\vert\vert(x,y)\vert\vert}=\lim_{\vert\vert(x,y)\vert\vert\rightarrow0}\frac{\vert f(x,y)\vert}{\vert\vert(x,y)\vert\vert}\leq \lim_{\vert\vert(x,y)\vert\vert\rightarrow0}\frac{\vert\vert(x,y)\vert\vert^2}{\vert\vert(x,y)\vert\vert}=0$$

**Edit**
As I understand it from the comments you want to prove that 
$\lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)}\frac{|R_{1,(a,b)}(x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0,$
where $R_{1,(a,b)}(x,y)=f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)-f_y(0,0)=f(x,y)-f_x(0,0)-f_y(0,0)$. To do this we have to prove that the partial derivatives of $f$ exist at $0$. Let's see that $f_x(0,0)$ exists (and it is $0$).
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\vert f(h,0)-f(0,0)\vert}{h}\leq\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{h^2}{h}=0.$$
Similarly for $f_y(0,0)$. Thus $R_{1,(a,b)}(x,y)=f(x,y)$ and you can argue as the first part of my answer to compute the limit.

Comment: so my claim's concerning the partial derivatives are correct?

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt Well, you cannot compute them. You don't know if they exist

Comment: how are you able to say that the partial derivatives should be 0 thenn

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt I am not saying that they exist and I don't need to. All I need is a linear function such that the first limit I wrote holds (this is the definition of differentiability at  a point)

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt A posteriori, the existence of the limit implies that the partial derivatives of $f$ exist in $(0,0)$ and are both $0$

Comment: Whats confusing me is that I am trying to determine if the limit = 0 therefore its existence isn't implied

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt What do you mean by 'its existence isn't implied'?

Comment: technically we haven't covered the definition of differentiability that includes the existence of a linear map, so our definition of differentiability is based on determining if the limit is 0

Comment: I think that you are missing a step. The definition of differentiability tells us that we can approximate our function by a linear one (in this case it tells us that there exists a plane tangent to $f$ at the origin). Now, once you have proved that this linear function exists you have to compute it and it turns out that it is given by the Jacobian of $f$ (in this case the gradient, which acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ through the scalar product)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83281/discussion-between-skrrrrrtttt-and-uskebasi).

Answer (score 0):

The function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is (totally) differentiable around $(0,0)$ if there exists a linear transformation $A\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\|f(x,y)-f(0,0) - A((x,y)-(0,0))\|}{\|(x,y)-(0,0)\|}=0. $$

Let $A$ be the zero transformation (i.e. $A(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y)$). From the inequality it follows that $f(0,0)=0$. Hence the limit becomes
 $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\|f(x,y)\|}{\|(x,y)\|} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 0.$$